# Tuple with number of components based on argument

Tags: typescript, types

Can I create a type that takes an argument `N` extending `number` and a type `T`, and returns a tuple with `N` components, each of type `T`?

Example:

```js
type A<N extends number, T> = [?];

type E1 = A<2, number>;  // [number, number]
type E2 = A<3, boolean>; // [boolean, boolean, boolean]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) with [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to implement this; for example:

```
type TupleLen<N extends number, T, A extends any[] = []> =
  N extends A['length'] ? A : TupleLen<N, T, [T, ...A]>;

type E1 = TupleLen<2, number>;  // [number, number]
type E2 = TupleLen<3, boolean>; // [boolean, boolean, boolean]
```

Of course, the compiler doesn't really allow you to do arbitrary math with numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and the above type function is therefore fragile.  If the `N` type parameter is specified with something you don't get as a `length` by recursively prepending to fixed-length tuples, you'll see some unfortunate behavior:

```
// don't write these unless you like to eat up your CPU
type Oops = TupleLen<-1, number>; //  
// error: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
type Oops2 = TupleLen<0.5, number>; //  
// error: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

One could try to harden `TupleLen` against such improper usages, at the expense of complexity.  I won't go into that here, since it's probably out of scope.  Anyway, that means you should  be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUCukA20Ay0B2AeAcrNAB6jYAmAzrFogLYBG0ATgDQJsCChJ5VAhlnABtALqwAvLFEA+CcFiwCxUlkqwOQgORosAc1AALTWID862AC4EyNJlx428NkKewAdB44jpAbhAQYWABRAEYJa1QMbBwAJjYaBmZfBQB6FKkExlZqOiyRMCg4IJjwpEi7HABmNnoAe1q0AWS0qTqG6AEa+sasLvaBfOAWslqsTVBYAHcmAEtSWENoCjhELDQKKnBaxFgUGYBrOFBawj4J5FgtxCZYAGEABQBVIfSAuAB5WsgqSTLbaIAtCF4rkkj5YC1ALwbgFJdyGAbp2YQhCrAZlgKKABKAZmcZqMUVRiABjJYUGYAN2gKHAsDI0GgkFgAjIsEgtQ2M3oVJRWAAZqi5tA3C8FsjPt8Sr8bFFcAAGNwAVhBiSYzXSMPhiPgyNR6Mx2KxeJmBKIxPZFK5tPpjNULLZpM51NRfKwArcQA)

Comment: Nice, thank you! I'd definitely love to see what can be done to harden it or make it more efficient.

Comment: You could harden it to only accept numbers between, say, `0` and `999` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpg37N) (it will just result in `never` otherwise). You could make it more efficient for large tuples like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m35Mkw) which should be logarithmic in the length of the tuple instead of linear... but yuck!  Both of these are hard to debug and explain, whereas the original version is vaguely intuitive (at least comparatively).  Do you think this stuff really belongs in the answer here? What are your use cases? (For `2` and `3` you don't need this complexity)